# Cannot get rails assets to compile and deploy correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

This is in the staging environment. I have in app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.scss which says:

```
.logo-div {

background-image:image-url("logo_white.png");

}
```

I also have app/assets/images/logo_white.png.

When I run bundle exec rake assets:precompile I do get a compiled application.css file as well as a fingerprinted version of logo_white.png (logo_white-204b61bda69f4aae0c9bb35ca909cdc2.png) file in my public/assets folder, but the image-url doesn't convert correctly, instead it comes out as:

```
background-image:url(/images/logo_white.png)
```

I would have expected it to look something like this:

```
background-image:url(/assets/logo_white-204b61bda69f4aae0c9bb35ca909cdc2.png)
```

Anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: If you are on the default settings you should run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ...` to make sure you use correct environment settings. `RAILS_ENV` is the environment variable rails will use to check with environment it should run at. It will default to "development".

Answer (score 0):

You'll get references to files in `/images/` (instead of `/assets/`) when Rails couldn't find the file specified.

I would double-check the spelling and file location of this `logo_white.png` - make sure it is in `/app/assets/images` and isn't spelt differently (eg. `logo-white.png` or `logo__white.png` or `logo_white.jpg`)

Answer (score 0):

If file logo_white.png located in another directory except images/, you need add to application.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/gallery"
```